# Adding dynamic bootstrap tab before the existing 'addition' tab

Tags: backbone.js, bootstrap-tabs

I'm working with backbone.js and have following `listView` for `<ul>` element and a separate `tabView` for dynamic `<li>` element. In the render method of `listView`, I'm creating a new `tabView` and appending that `el` to `listView` `el`.

```
var listView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //<ul> element for tabs
    el: '.nav-tabs',
    render: function(model) {
        var tabView = new TabView({ model: model });
        tabView.render();
        $(this.el).append(tabView.el);
    }
```

---

```
var TabView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //create <li> element to hold each tab
    tagName: "li",
    className: "currentTab ",
    render() {
        var html = this.template(this.model.attributes);
        $(this.el).append(html);
        //creates new div for tab content
        var tabContent = new TabContentView({ model: this.model });
        tabContent.render();
    }
```

This is fine and works as expected.

To add a new tab dynamically, I have a single `li` item at the start, so when the user clicks on that `li` item only new tab creation happens.

Now what I need is to add the newly creating tab before `li` + element. Currently all the new tabs are getting added only after `this` + element.

Following is the html of the `<ul>` tag for reference.

```
<div id="test">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
        <li><a href="#" class="add-newTab">+</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried out changing `listView` render method like below, but that doesn't work. Rather it just adds the new tab on top of (+) `li` element itself.

```
tabView.render();
$(this.el).find(".add-newTab").before(tabView.el);
```

Any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery offers `prepend` or `before` methods depending on what you really want.

## [`prepend`](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
    <li>prepending adds element here</li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="plus"><a href="#" class="add-newTab">+</a></li>
</ul>
```

## [`before`](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
    <li></li>
    <li>before adds element here when used on $('.plus')</li>
    <li class="plus"><a href="#" class="add-newTab">+</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's a simplified implementation of your list and tabs:

```
var TabView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //create <li> element to hold each tab
    tagName: "li",
    className: "currentTab", // why? all tabs will have "currentTab"

    initialize: function() {
        //creates new div for tab content
        this.tabContent = new TabContentView({
            model: this.model
        });
    },

    // render should only renders, and should be idempotent.
    render: function() {
        this.$el.empty().append(tabContent.render().el);

        // returning "this" is the default in Backbone, which enables
        // chaining method calls.
        return this; 
    }
});
```

---

```
var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //<ul> element for tabs
    el: '.nav-tabs',
    template: '<li class="plus"><a href="#" class="add-newTab">+</a></li>',
    events: {
        "click .add-newTab": "onAddTab",
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.empty().append(this.template);

        // cache the '+' li element.
        this.$plus = this.$('.plus');
        return this;
    },

    onAddTab: function(e) {
        var tabView = new TabView({ model: this.model });

        // the magic happens here.
        // if you want the tab at the beginning of the ul:
        this.$el.prepend(tabView.render().el);

        // or if you want it at the end, but before the + :
        this.$plus.before(tabView.render().el);
    },
});
```

You don't need to use the global jQuery to select elements, Backbone views have their own element pre-scoped and cached accessible through `this.$el`.

If you really need to find an element inside the view's `el`, you can select it using `this.$('.element-you-want')` which is a shortcut for:

```
$(this.el).find('.element-you-want')
```